# Debouncer in Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Simple question, but no documentation is to be found on the subject : is there a debouncer in Polymer 2.0? If so, how can it be used? 
`this.debounce` was an instance method in 1.0, but it appears to have disappeared.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Legacy 1.x debouncer

You can use the 1.x [`this.debounce()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-debounce) method via `Polymer.LegacyElementMixin`:

```
class XFoo extends Polymer.LegacyElementMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  ...
  _onClick() {
    this.debounce('myDebouncer', callback, 2000);
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gmRBJG?editors=1010)

#### New 2.x debouncer

The 2.0 equivalent is [`Polymer.Debouncer.debounce(debouncer, asyncModule, cb)`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/utils/debounce.html#L78), where:

- `debouncer`

  An instance of a `Polymer.Debouncer` returned from `Polymer.Debouncer.debounce()`, used to uniquely identify the debouncer job. This is the equivalent to the 1.x debouncer job name string. This can be initially `undefined`/`null` to create a new instance.
- `asyncModule`

  One of the following:

  - [`Polymer.Async.timeOut.after(TIMEOUT_MS)`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/utils/async.html#L57-L78)
  - [`Polymer.Async.idlePeriod`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/utils/async.html#L121-L129)
  - [`Polymer.Async.microTask`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/utils/async.html#L155-L169)
  - [`Polymer.Async.animationFrame`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/utils/async.html#L96-L103)
- `cb`

  Callback to invoke when the `asyncModule` completes

This function returns a [`Polymer.Debouncer`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/utils/debounce.html#L21) instance, which has a `cancel()` method, equivalent to 1.x [`this.cancelDebouncer(JOB_NAME)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-cancelDebouncer). That instance should be passed to the `debounce()` method on the next call for debouncing to work properly.

*Example usage:*

```
class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
  ...
  _onClick() {
    this._debouncer = Polymer.Debouncer.debounce(
       this._debouncer, // initially undefined
       Polymer.Async.timeOut.after(2000),
       callback);
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vxZVwx?editors=1010)

Comment: @CedricLaberge No problem :)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is the first argument for, most of the time you'll use the same reference as the one returned by the function. This looks hacky.

Comment: For anyone else blindly copying — `Polymer.Async.timeout.after` should in fact be `Polymer.Async.timeOut.after`  (uppercase O).